# PHP: change xdebug.profiler_output_name option in runtime

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

Can I change option xdebug.profiler_output_name in runtime to specify application modules profiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the profiler output name in the script, because the profiler starts before PHP starts your script. Hence, when the script starts, the file has already been created. You should be able to use `.htaccess` though,

The next version of Xdebug (2.3) will allow *starting* the profiler from the script, which then also will allow you to change the `xdebug.profiler_output_name` setting in the script (as long as you do it before starting the profiler of course).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet to print out whole objects and strings when var_dump-ing:

```
// make xdebug stop bugging me
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 1024);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 1048576);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 32);
```

Just replace the key with your `xdebug.profiler_output_name` and the desired value.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. I try to use ini_set('xdebug.profiler_output_name', 'some_name'). When I try echo ini_get('xdebug.profiler_output_name') - it was "cachegrind.out.%p"